# Grab random frames from video & make a gif image - Java

Tags: java, video, random, frames

I want to know if it's possible to grab random frames from a video and then "stick" these frames together to make a gif image?

I intend to achieve the above said idea by programming in Java.

What should I use? (I have no previous experience in programming involving videos, although am proficient in Java)

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Media Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/) let you do this kind of things

Answer (score 0):

Here's some source code using [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) that lets you get the raw images from a video.  Saving to an image from Java is then pretty straightforward.

[Sample Code](http://build.xuggle.com/view/Stable/job/xuggler_jdk5_stable/ws/workingcopy/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos/DecodeAndCaptureFrames.java).